# Creating a thread for running io_service

Tags: boost, boost-asio

Consider the chat example at : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html

Look the client  file : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/chat/chat_client.cpp

Here, seems like the point at which boost thread which runs the io_service is important..

```
chat_client c(io_service, iterator);

boost::thread t(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service));
```

If I create the thread before I create an object of chat_client, then the io_service.stopped() returns true if printed in the while loop below that.

I do not understand why it is so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is `io_service::run()` doing ?

> The run() function blocks until all work has finished and there are no more handlers to be dispatched, or until the io_service has been stopped.

when you call async function like (async_read,async_write, ...) you need to pass handlers to these functions. Handlers are called when async operation will be done. In `io_service::run()` async operations are being processed.

Before calling `io_service::run` at least one async operation must be waiting for executing. If you call `io_service::run` when there are no async operations planned, this method returns immediately. So

1. call first async operation
2. call `io_service::run` in thread to process async operations
3. when first async operation will be ended, you have to plan another async operation to execute so that `io_service::run` works (this method runs as long as there are async operations)

Look at constructor of `chat_client`

```
    socket_.async_connect(endpoint,
    boost::bind(&chat_client::handle_connect, this,
      boost::asio::placeholders::error, ++endpoint_iterator));
```

`async_connect` method is invoked - this is first async operation to be executed.

`io_service::stopped()` returns true when `io_service::run` ends working because there are no async operations to be processed.

> A normal exit from the run() function implies that the io_service object is stopped (the stopped() function returns true).